# Can I use Visual Studio 2010 for Kendo UI, Kendo UI Web or Kendo UI Mobile?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, kendo-ui

I only use one IDE (Visual Studio 2010), and preferred to stick with one IDE to keep it simple for me.

If I want to make something with Kendo UI, Kendo UI Web or Kendo UI Mobile, can I do this with Visual Studio 2010 instead of Eclipse? 
Bonus questions: And if not, why is that and will it come in the furture?

I found this fine [article](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-02-22/building_your_first_kendo_ui_mobile_phonegap_application.aspx), where he said Eclipse could be used, but never mention VS10. I have also search many other sites, but can't find anything, so I have to ask now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kendo UI is just js/html/css, so it should work just fine. Also telerik is a very .NET oriented company, I doubt they would release something that cannot be used from VS.

Here you have an answer to your question from a Kendo forum admin:
http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/general-discussions/setting-up-visual-studio-2010-with-kendoui.aspx

Answer (score 1):

ntziolis is correct.  I would just note that Telerik has not yet added .vsdoc versions of their javascript, so intellisense will be lacking.  Telerik says maybe in q2, 2012.

Here's a post about it from the [forum](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/general-discussions/intellisense-in-visual-studio.aspx)